# Meteor Table Data Being Reordered

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have started building a meteor application that has a table with data loaded from a collection. I want the user to be able to double click on a field and edit it. I have achieved this functionality but when I update the document in the collection the table redraws and the updated document is at the bottom of the table, out of order from the other rows, which have not been updated. This happens to all updated rows.

Any insight into this problem would be greatly appreciated. This is my first meteor application so do not know why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest removing the meteor autopublish package and write your own publish function.
There you can add an explicit sort specifier otherwise there is no real way to ensure order of the items in your collection. Somewhat like this:

```
Meteor.publish("all-items", function() { return Items.find({}, {sort: ["name", "asc"]})})
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Does the publish function go in the server code and do I also need a subscribe function as well?

Comment: That's both correct. The publish function should be on the server-side, and once you disable autopublish you will need to subscribe to that published collection.